# How to send request with content-type is form-data?

Tags: java, jmeter, dsl

The problem is: how to send a request with the body which has content-type Form-data and also this request body should contain saved parameter from the previous response

The code is:

```
TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
    threadGroup(1, 1),
             httpSampler(firstRequestUrl)
                    .method(POST)
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header(AUTHORIZATION, getToken())
                    .body(someBody)
                    .children(new DslJsr223PostProcessor("Get param",
                    "def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())\n" +
                            "def paramValue = jsonResponse.param\n" +
                            "vars.put('paramKey', paramValue)")),
            httpSampler(secondRequestUrl)
                    .method(POST)
                    .contentType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                    .body(here need to provide form body with "${paramKey}")
                    .children(new DslJsr223PostProcessor("Get response status code",
                            "int statusCode = prev.getResponseCode();\n" +
                                    "vars.put('responseStatusCode', String.valueOf(statusCode));"
                    )),
            new DslJsr223Sampler("Print result",
                    "String result = vars.get('responseStatusCode');" +
                            "if (result != null) {\n" +
                            "    println('csrfKey: ' + result);\n" +
                            "} else {\n" +
                            "    println('result not found');\n" +
                            "}")

    ).rampTo(testParams.getThreads(), Duration.ofMinutes(testParams.getRumpUpTime())),
    influxDbListener(envSetting.getInfluxDbUrl())
            .measurement("someMeasurement")
).run();
```

From the first httpSampler(), I save the parameter into the JMeter vars map.

In the second httpSampler(), I need to send a request with content-type Form-data and this request should contain saved in the JMeter vars map param "${paramKey}"

The request body should contain parameters:

- param1 = "${paramKey}"
- param2 = 10.01
- param3 = "SomeText1"
- param4 = false
- param5.key1 = 11111
- param5.key2 = "SomeText2"
- param5.key3 = 22222

The signature of the method `body(Function<PreProcessorVars, String> bodySupplier)` or `body(String body)`.

How do I build a proper request body with these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
httpSampler(secondRequestUrl)
        .method(POST)
        .bodyPart("param1", "${paramKey}", TEXT_PLAIN)
        .bodyPart("param2", "10.01", TEXT_PLAIN)
        //etc
        .bodyFilePart("foo", "/path/to/your/file", APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

will generate the HTTP Request sampler looking like:

[image]

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter DSL User Guide](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/guide/)
- [JMeter DSL: Bringing Performance Testing Closer to Developers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dsl)